# Python Debugger Freezing After 5 Lines of Code

Tags: python, debugging, anaconda, spyder, keyboardinterrupt

What to do when the python debugger seems to get stuck after running the first few (five) lines of code?

I have been using Python for quite a while, but starting yesterday, I have not been able to use the debugger. Whenever i try to run the debugger, it just displays the first 5 lines of the script and then stops.
If I then try to exit out of the debugger, it just displayer `--KeyboardInterrupt--` but it does not terminate the process.

I am running Python 3.9 with Spyder, and have tried fixing it by restarting, resetting to factory setting, installing into a new environment, as well as a total uninstall and clear, and then installing from scratch, but nothing seems to work.

Even when i try running really basic scripts (like the images below) the result is the same

[**Running basic scripts normally (F5) works fine**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMQc4.png)

[**But debugging just gets stuck**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw48i.png)

[**And terminating the debugger process is not possible**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My4l5.png)

Comment: Please don't post text and code as images.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)